# Writing directly below an equation

Tags: equations, align

I want to write an equation with matrices and underneath that equation I want to define the name of the matrices.

[image]

Something like this. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You couls use  the `\underbracket` command from `mathtools`.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

---

*Addendum*, prompted by a comment of @egreg: For the objects at hand, the underbrackets may well be excessively thick. One can override the default thickness by adding an optional argument to the `\underbracket` macro. E.g., you could replace

```
\underbracket{\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}}_{\coloneqq a}
```

with

```
\underbracket[0.7pt]{\begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix}}_{\coloneqq a}
```

Do give thickness values between `0.4pt` and `1pt` a try and decide which value ends up producing underbrackets that appear to have the "right" thickness.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
{\underbracket{
   \begin{pmatrix}
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot  
   \end{pmatrix}}_{\coloneqq a}}
\cdot
{\underbracket{
   \begin{pmatrix}
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
   \end{pmatrix}}_{\coloneqq b}}
=
{\underbracket{
   \begin{pmatrix}
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
      \cdot & \cdot & \cdot
   \end{pmatrix}}_{\coloneqq c}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks this works perfect

Comment: I'd use less heavy brackets and also `\textstyle` in the subscripts. Or, at least `\;` after `\coloneqq`. Of course I'd never use `\coloneqq`, but it's a different topic.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've added a paragraph to explain how users may change a non-default value for the thickness of the underbrackets.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using Unicode math then `\underbracket` is defined. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]
$$
  \underbracket{\pmatrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&f}}_{=a}
  \cdot
  \underbracket{\pmatrix{u&v\cr w&x\cr y&z}}_{=b}
  =
  \underbracket{\pmatrix{p&q\cr r&s}}_{=b}
$$
\bye
```

[image: underbracket]